# understanding precision and scale on a property

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

```
property name="poiLat" length="60" ormtype="big_decimal" persistent=true precision="16" scale="14" default="0" hint="";
```

I don't understand precision or scale correctly. Using the property above why would '1' give an error and '2' be accepted? what should I change it to to accept '1'

1 ) -118.27  = error

2)  -18.27  = ok

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Scale refers the number of digits to the **right** of the decimal place. If you have precision 16 and scale 14, you can only have 2 digits to the **left** of the decimal place, so

```
18.12345678901234 = ok 
118.27 = error
```

Try:

```
precision="16" scale="13"
```

That will allow 118.1234567890123, but that is a lot of decimal places. How many do you really need?

```
precision="16" scale="4"
```

Will allow 123456789012.1234